# CosmosDB - Connect while App Running on 3rd Party Hosting

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I have created a Node.js application, and a CosmosDB database.

When I connect to the CosmosDB database locally, all my Database calls work as expected, data is populated and updated in CosmosDB.

However, when I deploy the app to a 3rd Party Hosting site, my Database calls hang indefinitely. I have checked the configuration of the database connection, then environment variables on the server, etc., and am confident I have set everything up correctly.

Previously, I had deployed the app via App Service, and all worked fine as well, so I am very confident the issue has something to do with the fact that I am using 3rd party hosting. The app starts and, other than the database calls, works as expected on the 3rd party hosting site.

I have contacted the 3rd Party Hosting provider, and they say all looks normal on their end.

I am using the MongoDB CosmosDB API.

Is there something that I have to configure in Azure Portal, or something that might be blocking the connection when it is deployed using 3rd party hosting? Help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: It's very clear what you describe. Where ConsmosDB is connected, it is recommended to log in the code or provide error information to better locate the problem.

Comment: Hi Jason, there are no errors thrown either within the application or on the 3rd party hosting server logs. The requests simply hang, and don't return.

Comment: I mean, when you start the program or when you call cosmosdb, you ` try...catch...`  in the code to connect to the database. Record timeout or other error information in `.txt` file or database, you can better troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: In addition, please set the firewall network limit of cosmosdb to `allow all networks` for test.

Comment: After ensuring that there is no problem with the above operation, then the problem is probably the firewall `outband` configuration of the third-party server. To troubleshoot this issue, we can use `WireShark` to capture packets to see if they are deployed in third-party applications, have any requests to communicate with cosmosdb and check the connection status at startup.

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you. I have confirmed the firewall settings on CosmosDB "Allow all networks". I added a try.. catch.. block to the file that makes the database connection and it is now working. That is the only change i made. I'm not sure why, but I did have a ticket with the 3rd party hosting service, so maybe they made changes in the background. I can't think of anything else that would have been impacting it. Thank you for your time.